# VSCode/Prettier/EsLint adding spaces in optional chaining operator

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, typescript-eslint

Not sure what's going on, but in VSCode w/ ESLint and Prettier turned on, it keeps converting lines like this `var?.foo?.bar` into `var ? .foo ? .bar` which then throws syntax errors... I have the following:

```
{
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true
  }
```

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "airbnb-typescript"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "rules": {
   "@typescript-eslint/semi": "off",
   "semi": "off",
   "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
   "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "next" }],
   "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
   "react/jsx-one-expression-per-line": "off",
   "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
   "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": "off",
   "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"] }],
   "react/function-component-definition": "off",
   "react/require-default-props": "off",
   "no-param-reassign": "off"
  }
}
```

How do I stop VSCode from adding those spaces?

Comment: hello, do you find any fix to this problem? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Nope still nothing yet :(

Comment: Hi @BradHerman. have you fixed this issue? I am asking as I have the same issue. :pray:

Comment: I reinstalled VSCode and my extensions... As others have mentioned, it is possibly caused by Beautify, which I also had installed at the time.  Make sure ESLint is formatting the file and not Beautify

Answer (score 2):

I may be a bit late here, but at least for me, this issue was caused by VSCode using a 'Beautify' formatter from another extension, rather than ESlint. I had to open the command palette (`Ctrl + Shift + P`), then select `>Format document with...`, then at the bottom select `Configure default formatter`, and select ESlint as the default.

Answer (score 1):

I Installed Eslint extension and choose it as the default value for formatting .js files

and it works fine